# How to get original exception back from std::exception once caught?

Tags: c++

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

void log(const std::exception& e) {
  try {
      throw e;
  }
  catch (const std::logic_error& e1) {
      std::cout << "logic_error: " << e1.what() << std::endl; // How to get logic_error back once caught?
  }
  catch (const std::exception& e1) {
      std::cout << "exception: " << e1.what() << std::endl;
  } 
}

int main()
{
  try {
      throw std::logic_error("sth wrong");
  }
  catch (const std::exception& e) {
      log(e);
  }
}
```

I don't want to add more catch clauses is because I want to have a central place to log detailed exception message, it could be very different across different exceptions.

Is there a way to narrow down the std::exception to derived exception in the catch clause?

Comment: Just add more `catch` blocks with appropriate exception types, what is the problem here? *"How to get logic_error back once caught"* - do you mean rethrow or what?

Comment: @VTT just added more description.

Comment: The question still does not make sense, you already catching `logic_error`. If you want to rethrow currently cought exception then you should write just `throw;` instead of `throw e;`

Comment: @VTT I think all he (and I) neglected is `throw;`.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` ?

Comment: @VTT interesting, I don't know I can do `throw` before. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your question, it makes it very confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rethrow the original exception in your `log` method to preserve its original state. This way everything should work as you would expect it.

Modified `log` method looks like this:

```
void log(const std::exception& e) {
  try {
      throw;
  }
  catch (const std::logic_error& e1) {
      std::cout << "logic_error: " << e1.what() << std::endl;
  }
  catch (const std::exception& e1) {
      std::cout << "exception: " << e1.what() << std::endl;
  } 
}
```

See [throw expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) for more details on how `throw e` and `throw` differs in this example.

Comment: I know I can `throw` in the catch clause in main function. I don't know I can also throw in the `log` function before. Your solution is what I want.

Comment: You can get rid of input parameter that you don't use.

Comment: And "issue" is that `log` can only be called from catch clause (without compiler check).

Comment: A minor point: with this change, the argument `e` is no longer needed.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::exception::what()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/what/) is `virtual`. So you don't need to get back the original type to write the logs. You just have to ensure that `what()` is redefined for your custom exceptions that inherits `std::exception`.

This may become:

```
void log(const std::exception & e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I need to handle more specific informations related with derived exceptions, not only the `what()` information.

Comment: @user1633272 Oh, sorry, the example you provided only used `what()`, I missed the point that you need more, my bad.

Comment: @user1633272 But if you need specific child classes member functions, I'm afraid you cannot avoid to catch each exception, because calling a method from one will not work from another since they don't share the same members (except `what()`).

Comment: I don't want to avoid catching each exception, I just want to have a separated function like `log` to handle the logging logic. It will make the `main` function more clear.

Comment: @user1633272 Ah ok, I thought you wanted to make the `log()` function clearer. I did not understand that you was talking about the `main()`.

Answer (score 3):

You might use [`std::rethrow_exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/rethrow_exception):

```
void log(std::exception_ptr eptr) {
    try {
        if (eptr) {
            std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
        }
    }
    catch (const std::logic_error& e1) {
        std::cout << "logic_error: " << e1.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e1) {
        std::cout << "exception: " << e1.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    try {
        throw std::logic_error("sth wrong");
    }
    catch (const std::exception&) { // or even catch (...)
        log(std::current_exception());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use only base exceptions provided by the standard library, you can make your own exception hierarchy with the methods you need.

```cpp
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class MyBaseException: public std::exception
{
public:
   virtual std::string output() const = 0;
   /* Define methods you need here */
};

class MySpecificException : public MyBaseException
{
public:
    const char* what() const noexcept override  {return "error"; }
    std::string output() const override { return "Specific debug output that I want"; }
};


int main(){
    try{
         throw MySpecificException{};
    }catch(const MyBaseException& e){
         std::cout << e.output() << '\n';
    }catch(const std::exception& e) {
         std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use run time type information to get the type of the execption:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <typeinfo>
#if defined(__clang__) || defined(__GNUC__)
#include <cxxabi.h>
#endif

std::string getTypename(const std::exception& e)
{
    #if defined(__clang__) || defined(__GNUC__)
    // .name() returns a mangled name on gcc and clang
    int status;
    return abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid( e ).name(), 0, 0, &status);
    #else
    // visual studio returns a human readable name
    return typeid( e ).name();
    #endif    
}

void log(const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << getTypename( e ) << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  try {
      throw std::logic_error("sth wrong");
  }
  catch (const std::exception& e) {
      log(e);
  }
}
```

The `getTypename()` method may not work on all platforms and you might need to adjust it to your needs. You might want to use [boost::core::demangle](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/demangle.html) rather than calling the gcc demangle API directly.